# Проблема с вызовом функции JS на странице html через onclick в теге <input>

Tags: javascript, html

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 16px Arial;  
}

/* контейнер должен быть расположен относительно друг друга: */
.autocomplete {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input[type=text] {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  /* расположите элементы автозаполнения на той же ширине, что и контейнер: */
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4; 
}

/* при наведении курсора на элемент: */
.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  background-color: #e9e9e9; 
}

/* при навигации по элементам используйте клавиши со стрелками: */
.autocomplete-active {
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important; 
  color: #ffffff; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>     
<body>

<h1>Функция автозаполнения</h1>

<p>Начните печатать:</p>

<!--Убедитесь, что в форме отключена функция автозаполнения:-->
<form autocomplete="off" action="../action_page.php">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    `<input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Страна" onclick = "autocomplete('myInput')">`
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
function autocomplete(inp) {
  /*функция автозаполнения принимает два аргумента,
    элемент текстового поля и массив возможных значений автозаполнения:*/
  inp = document.getElementById(inp);
  var currentFocus;
  var arr = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua",Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda","Bhutan","Bolivia","Bosnia & Herzegovina","Botswana","Brazil","British Virgin Islands","Brunei","Bulgaria","Burkina Faso","Burundi","Cambodia","Cameroon","Canada","Cape Verde","Cayman Islands","Central Arfrican Republic","Chad","Chile","China","Colombia","Congo","Cook Islands","Costa Rica","Cote D Ivoire","Croatia","Cuba","Curacao","Cyprus","Czech Republic","Denmark","Djibouti","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Ecuador","Egypt","El Salvador","Equatorial Guinea","Eritrea","Estonia","Ethiopia","Falkland Islands","Faroe Islands","Fiji","Finland","France","French Polynesia","French West Indies","Gabon","Gambia","Georgia","Germany","Ghana","Gibraltar","Greece","Greenland","Grenada","Guam","Guatemala","Guernsey","Guinea","Guinea Bissau","Guyana","Haiti","Honduras","Hong Kong","Hungary","Iceland","India","Indonesia","Iran","Iraq","Ireland","Isle of Man","Israel","Italy","Jamaica","Japan","Jersey","Jordan","Kazakhstan","Kenya","Kiribati","Kosovo","Kuwait","Kyrgyzstan","Laos","Latvia","Lebanon","Lesotho","Liberia","Libya","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Macau","Macedonia","Madagascar","Malawi","Malaysia","Maldives","Mali","Malta","Marshall Islands","Mauritania","Mauritius","Mexico","Micronesia","Moldova","Monaco","Mongolia","Montenegro","Montserrat","Morocco","Mozambique","Myanmar","Namibia","Nauro","Nepal","Netherlands","Netherlands Antilles","New Caledonia","New Zealand","Nicaragua","Niger","Nigeria","North Korea","Norway","Oman","Pakistan","Palau","Palestine","Panama","Papua New Guinea","Paraguay","Peru","Philippines","Poland","Portugal","Puerto Rico","Qatar","Reunion","Romania","Russia","Rwanda","Saint Pierre & Miquelon","Samoa","San Marino","Sao Tome and Principe","Saudi Arabia","Senegal","Serbia","Seychelles","Sierra Leone","Singapore","Slovakia","Slovenia","Solomon Islands","Somalia","South Africa","South Korea","South Sudan","Spain","Sri Lanka","St Kitts & Nevis","St Lucia","St Vincent","Sudan","Suriname","Swaziland","Sweden","Switzerland","Syria","Taiwan","Tajikistan","Tanzania","Thailand","Timor L'Este","Togo","Tonga","Trinidad & Tobago","Tunisia","Turkey","Turkmenistan","Turks & Caicos","Tuvalu","Uganda","Ukraine","United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom","United States of America","Uruguay","Uzbekistan","Vanuatu","Vatican City","Venezuela","Vietnam","Virgin Islands (US)","Yemen","Zambia","Zimbabwe"];
  /*выполните функцию, когда кто-то пишет в текстовом поле:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      /*закройте все уже открытые списки значений автозаполнения*/
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      /*создайте элемент DIV, который будет содержать элементы (значения):*/
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      /*добавьте элемент DIV в качестве дочернего элемента контейнера автозаполнения:*/
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
      /*для каждого элемента массива...*/
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        /*проверьте, начинается ли элемент с тех же букв, что и значение текстового поля:*/
        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
          /*создайте элемент DIV для каждого соответствующего элемента:*/
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          /*сделайте соответствующие буквы жирными:*/
          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          /*вставьте поле ввода, которое будет содержать значение текущего элемента массива:*/
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
          /*выполните функцию, когда кто-то нажимает на значение элемента (DIV элемент):*/
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              /*вставьте значение для текстового поля автозаполнения:*/
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              /*закройте список значений автозаполнения,
              (или любые другие открытые списки значений автозаполнения:*/
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });
  /*выполнение функции нажатие клавиши на клавиатуре:*/
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        /*Если нажата клавиша со стрелкой вниз,
          увеличьте текущую переменную фокуса:*/
        currentFocus++;
        /*и сделать текущий элемент более заметным:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //вверх
        /*Если нажата клавиша со стрелкой вверх,
          уменьшите текущую переменную фокуса:*/
        currentFocus--;
        /*и сделать текущий элемент более заметным:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        /*Если нажата клавиша ENTER, не допускайте отправки формы,*/
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          /*и имитировать щелчок по "активному" пункту:*/
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
  function addActive(x) {
    /*функция для классификации элемента как " активного":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    /*начните с удаления "активного" класса на всех элементах:*/
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    /*добавить класс "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    /*функция для удаления класса "active" из всех элементов автозаполнения:*/
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    /*закройте все списки автозаполнения в документе,
    за исключением того, что было передано в качестве аргумента:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  /*выполните функцию, когда кто-то щелкает в документе:*/
  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, браток, ты лучший

Answer (score 0):

Если воспользоваться простейшим редактором кода (я смотрел в Sublime Text), то там подсветятся ошибки синтаксиса. При перечислении массива arr вы не открыли кавычки перед Barbuda. Возможно проблема была в этом, весь ваш код я не проверял.
Было бы лучше если бы вы в песочнице разместили ваш код, а сюда скинули ссылку на нее. Было бы больше желающих вам помочь.